# Python: Calling multiple inits in Multiple inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-2.x, multiple-inheritance

I have 2 classes: A (which needs 1 argument to initialize) and B (which needs 2 arguments to initialize), and a third class C which derives from both A and B.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, sval): 
        print("A: rcd value: ", sval)
        self.aval = sval

class B: 
    def __init__(self, sval, tval):
        print("B: rcd 2 values: ", sval, tval)
        self.aval=sval
        self.bval=tval

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super().__init__(a) 
        super().__init__(b,c) # error here

c = C(1,2,3)
```

When I run above code, there is error at the last line; `__init__` of class A is called, not that of class B.

```
A: rcd value:  1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inheritance.py", line 20, in <module>
    c = C(1,2,3)
  File "inheritance.py", line 16, in __init__
    super().__init__(b,c) 
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

How can I call `__init__` functions of both A and B from `__init__` of class C?

Edit: I am using Python 3.5.3 on Debian Linux, though I will prefer a solution which works on both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: I've added a `Python-2.x` and `Python-3.x` tag as you never specified which version of Python you were using, and the solution works for both

Comment: You have a conflict to resolve: both `A` and `B` have attributes named `aval`; one needs to be renamed. If you don't have control over `A` or `B`, then you're going to have to define an adaptor for one of them.

Comment: The right way to use `super` is to have both `A` and `B` use it as well, then use `super` *once* from `C.__init__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have control over `A` and `B` and can avoid using the same attribute name in both. Then in order to correctly use `super`, define them as follows.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, aval, **kwargs): 
        print("A: rcd value: ", aval)
        self.aval = sval
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class B: 
    def __init__(self, b1val, b2val, **kwargs):
        print("B: rcd 2 values: ", b1val, b2val)
        self.b1val = b1val
        self.b2val = b2val
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Then `C.__init__` needs to call `super` only *once*:

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, aval, b1val, b2val, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(aval=aval, b1val=b1val, b2val=b2val, **kwargs)

c = C(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Any drawbacks of the solution by AK47 ?

Comment: At least as written, it doesn't handle the conflicting `aval` attributes defined in `A` and `B`; `B.__init__` simply overwrites the value set by `A.__init__`. Also (again extending this beyond the original question) if `A` and `B` shared a common base class, it's `__init__` method (assuming both `A` and `B` properly called it) would be called twice, which could cause problems, depending on its definition.

Comment: In the end, though, both approaches require some care about how the classes involved are defined. I would never say it is absolutely *wrong* to explicitly call parent class methods instead of using `super`; you just need to be aware of the pros and cons of each, and use the one most appropriate to your class hierarchy.

Comment: Great explanation. I think you can put these comments in your answer itself where they are more likely to be read by other users.

Answer (score 2):

Call `A.__init__()` and `B.__init__()` instead of `super().__init__()`

```
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        A.__init__(self, a) 
        B.__init__(self, b, c)
```

Python 3 (https://repl.it/repls/CooperativeTransparentRobot):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, sval): 
        print("A: rcd value: ", sval)
        self.aval = sval

class B: 
    def __init__(self, sval, tval):
        print("B: rcd 2 values: ", sval, tval)
        self.aval=sval
        self.bval=tval

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        A.__init__(self, a) 
        B.__init__(self, b,c) # this does not give error

c = C(1,2,3)

>> Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
>> [GCC 4.8.2] on linux
>> A: rcd value:  1
>> B: rcd 2 values:  2 3
```

Also works in Python 2:
https://repl.it/repls/GreenAbleBlockchain

Comment: Can I leave first super call as it is: `super().__init__(a)`  and only use `B.__init__(self, b, c)` ?

Comment: Yes, but dont pass `self` to `super().__init__()`

Comment: I altered the comment on the line which was giving error earlier. This method works well but answer by @chepner seems much more broad based.

Comment: @AK47 Note that when you call `B.__init__`, it overwrites the `aval` set by `A.__init__`. That's not really a problem with using `A.__init__` and `B.__init__` explicitly, just with `C` inheriting from two conflicting classes.